# Issue with an infinite while loop while trying detect if a string is embedded in another string

Tags: java, string, while-loop, infinite-loop

For a class project, I need to fix up some code to make it function, with the goal of creating a method that takes two inputs, two strings. If 'keyword' is embedded within another word in 's', or not present, it returns -1, otherwise it returns the index of the first instance of 'keyword' within 's' that is not embedded in another word.

However, every time I run the code, I'm getting an infinite loop error. I've realized the removing the '!' from line 30 allows the code to run, but outputs an entirely wrong answer for every occurrence. Does anyone know why I'm getting this infinite loop error, or how to make this code function. Thanks!

```
public static int indexOfKeyword(String s, String keyword) {
// Change both s and keyword to lower case
s = s.toLowerCase();
keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();

// The index of the first occurrence (perhaps embedded) of keyword in s
int startIdx = s.indexOf(keyword);

// Check if this occurrence is embedded and look further down s if it is
while (startIdx >= 0) {
    // Find the substrings of length 1 immediately before and after
    // this occurrence. Default to the string " " containing only a space.
    String before = " ", after = " ";

    if (startIdx > 0) {
        before = s.substring(s.indexOf(keyword));
    }

    int endIdx = s.indexOf(keyword) + keyword.length();

    if (endIdx < s.length()) {
        after = s.substring(endIdx);
    }

    // If before and after aren't letters, this is the first whole word occurrence
    if (!((before.compareTo("a") >= 0 && before.compareTo("z") <= 0) &&
            (after.compareTo("a") >= 0 && after.compareTo("z") <= 0.))) {
        return startIdx;
    }

    // This is not a whole word occurrence. Move to the next occurrence.
    startIdx = s.indexOf(keyword, endIdx);
}

return -1;
}
```

Comment: The line `before = s.substring(s.indexOf(keyword));` looks wrong. That's `s.substring(startIdx)` which must mean `s` from the keyword onward, not before.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of finding `before` and `after` are pretty funky, aren't you only supposed to find the single character before and after the keyword? Because right now you're setting multiple characters as the before and after. Something like this should work.

```
before = s.charAt(s.indexOf(keyword)-1);
after = s.charAt(endIdx)+1;
```

Then to check if `before` and `after` are spaces

```
if(before == ' ' && after == ' '){
    //the keyword is not embedded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, before is supposed to find the character before the occurrence, yet your finding the substring from the index of where you occurrence starts?

Also i believe your endIdx variable has an off by 1 error, should be startIdx + keyword.length - 1

Answer (score 0):

First, the `before` should be:

```
        before = s.substring(startIdx - 1, startIdx);
```

And the `if` should be:

```
        // If before and after aren't letters, this is the first whole word occurrence
        if ((!(before.compareTo("a") >= 0 && before.compareTo("z") <= 0) && !(after.compareTo("a") >= 0 && after.compareTo("z") <= 0))) {
            return startIdx;
        }
```

Full Code:

```
public static int indexOfKeyword(String s, String keyword) {
    // Change both s and keyword to lower case
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();

    // The index of the first occurrence (perhaps embedded) of keyword in s
    int startIdx = s.indexOf(keyword);

    // Check if this occurrence is embedded and look further down s if it is
    while (startIdx >= 0) {
        // Find the substrings of length 1 immediately before and after
        // this occurrence. Default to the string " " containing only a space.
        String before = " ", after = " ";

        if (startIdx > 0) {
            before = s.substring(startIdx - 1, startIdx);
        }

        int endIdx = s.indexOf(keyword) + keyword.length();

        if (endIdx < s.length()) {
            after = s.substring(endIdx);
        }

        // If before and after aren't letters, this is the first whole word occurrence
        if ((!(before.compareTo("a") >= 0 && before.compareTo("z") <= 0) && !(after.compareTo("a") >= 0 && after
                .compareTo("z") <= 0))) {
            return startIdx;
        }

        // This is not a whole word occurrence. Move to the next occurrence.
        startIdx = s.indexOf(keyword, endIdx);
    }

    return -1;
}
```